# png file black background showed in ios with using sdwebimage

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, sdwebimage

When I use `UIImageView` to `setImage` (The image is from the remote server), the image data must be cached,so I use `sdwebimage` to do it.

then I run the simulator, the image is showed with black background.the code is that:

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dic objectForKey:@"icon_url"]]]
```

The image file from remote server is a .png file with transparent. ps:when I use `UIImageView 's` setImage Function ,it works well,but can't be cached.
How can I solve it? Does anybody can help?